# Shopify API upload a local image via python

Tags: python-2.7, shopify

```
import shopify
from base64 import b64encode
#omitted the shopify key
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)


path = "product.jpg"

new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "title"
new_product.body_html = "This is a test"

image = shopify.Image()

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    filename = path.split("/")[-1:][0]
    #encoded = b64encode(f.read()) (I tried this one as well)
    encoded = f.read()
    image.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename)

new_product.images = image
new_product.save()
```

I tested both methods:

- `encoded = b64encode(f.read())`
- `encoded = f.read()`

In both tests, the output was the same:

The product was successfully created, however, with no image.

I also noticed that the `image` returns `image(None)` and `new_products.images` returns `image(None)` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close- the `new_product.images` attribute must be a *list* of `Image` instances, not an `Image` instance. Also, if you look at [the source](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/13074053cefdc6ceb6cddcf06c58d3401dfa82a3/shopify/resources/image.py#L25) of `attach_image()`, you can see they do the base64 encoding for you.

```
import shopify
#omitted the shopify key
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)

path = "product.jpg"

new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "title"
new_product.body_html = "This is a test"

image = shopify.Image()

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    filename = path.split("/")[-1:][0]
    encoded = f.read()
    image.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename)

new_product.images = [image] # Here's the change
new_product.save()
```

Comment: how would you do 2 pictures?

Answer (score 0):

self.fake("products/632910392/images", method='POST', body=self.load_fixture('image'), headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})

image = shopify.Image({'product_id':632910392})

image.position = 1

binary_in=base64.b64decode("R0lGODlhbgCMAPf/APbr48VySrxTO7IgKt2qmKQdJeK8lsFjROG5p/nz7Zg3MNmnd7Q1MLNVS9GId71hSJMZIuzTu4UtKbeEeakhKMl8U8WYjfr18YQaIbAf==")

image.attach_image(data=binary_in, filename='ipod-nano.png')

image.save()